# Multiplying two decimal integer with divide and conquer java

Tags: java, divide-and-conquer, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two numbers which they're positive integer and they have same number of digits,with divide and conquer recursively,i'm trying to do it something like that: T(n)=4T(n/2)+O(n)
note:i know that it runs in theta(n^2),and it's terrible!it's just a exercise for me.
thank you,and sorry for my bad english. :)
and my question:where is my mistake?
[algorithm based on this doc](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~rezaul/Fall-2012/CSE548/CSE548-lecture-2.pdf)
here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
static int res=0;
static int stage =0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] Num1;
    char[] Num2;
    String num1 = in.nextLine();
    String num2 = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
    Num1 = num1.toCharArray();
    Num2 = num2.toCharArray();



    DaQMultiplay(Num1, Num2);
    System.out.println(res);
}
static int DaQMultiplay(char[] num1,char[] num2){
    if(num1.length<2){
        stage++;
        int num1sd =Integer.parseInt(new String(num1));
        int num2sd =Integer.parseInt(new String(num2));
        return (num1sd*num2sd);
    }
    stage++;
    double len = num1.length;
    int lenl = (int) Math.ceil(len/2);
    char []ln1 = new char[lenl];
    char []rn1 = new char[(int) (len-lenl)];
    char []ln2 = new char[lenl];
    char []rn2 = new char[(int) (len-lenl)];
    for (int i = 0; i < ln1.length; i++) {
        ln1[i]=num1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rn1.length; i++) {
        rn1[i]=num1[i+lenl];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ln2.length; i++) {
        ln2[i]=num2[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rn2.length; i++) {
        rn2[i]=num2[i+lenl];
    }
    System.out.print("Left Side of num1:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(ln1);

    System.out.print("Right Side of num1:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(rn1);

    System.out.print("Left Side of num2:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(ln2);

    System.out.print("Right Side of num2:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(rn2);


    res+=DaQMultiplay(ln1,ln2)*(10^((int)len));
    System.out.println("res: "+res);
    res+=DaQMultiplay(ln1,rn2)*10^((int) (len-lenl));
    System.out.println("res: "+res);
    res+=DaQMultiplay(rn1,ln2)*10^((int) (len-lenl));
    System.out.println("res: "+res);
    res+=DaQMultiplay(rn1, rn2);
    System.out.println("res: "+res);
    return 0;
}
}
```

output: for num1=20011,num2=91281

```
    20011
91281
Left Side of num1:1 200
Right Side of num1:1 11
Left Side of num2:1 912
Right Side of num2:1 81
Left Side of num1:2 20
Right Side of num1:2 0
Left Side of num2:2 91
Right Side of num2:2 2
Left Side of num1:3 2
Right Side of num1:3 0
Left Side of num2:3 9
Right Side of num2:3 1
res: 144
res: 164
res: 164
res: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at main.DaQMultiplay(main.java:46)
at main.DaQMultiplay(main.java:63)
at main.DaQMultiplay(main.java:61)
at main.main(main.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the complete program and everything is working fine:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] Num1;
        char[] Num2;
        String num1 = in.nextLine();
        String num2 = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
        Num1 = num1.toCharArray();
        Num2 = num2.toCharArray();  
        check(Num1, Num2);
    }
    static int DaQMultiplay(char[] num1,char[] num2){
        int res=0;
        if(num1.length<=1){
            int num1sd = 0;
            int num2sd = 0;
            if(num1!=null && !num1.equals("") && new String(num2).trim().length()>0){
                num1sd =Integer.parseInt(new String(num1));
            }

            if(num2!=null && !num2.equals("") && new String(num2).trim().length()>0){
                num2sd=Integer.parseInt(new String(num2));
            }
            return (num1sd*num2sd);
        }
        double len = num1.length;
        int lenl = (int) Math.ceil(len/2);
        char []ln1 = new char[lenl];
        char []rn1 = new char[(int) (len-lenl)];
        char []ln2 = new char[lenl];
        char []rn2 = new char[(int) (len-lenl)];
        for (int i = 0; i < ln1.length; i++) {
            ln1[i]=num1[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rn1.length; i++) {
            rn1[i]=num1[i+lenl];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ln2.length; i++) {
            ln2[i]=num2[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rn2.length; i++) {
            if(num2.length>i+lenl){
                rn2[i]=num2[i+lenl];
            }
        }

        res+=(DaQMultiplay(ln1,ln2)*(Math.pow(10, len)));
        res+=(DaQMultiplay(rn1,ln2)*(Math.pow(10, (len/2))));
        res+=(DaQMultiplay(ln1,rn2)*(Math.pow(10, (len/2))));
        res+=(DaQMultiplay(rn1, rn2));

        return res;
    }
    static void check(char []Num1,char []Num2){
        int res=0;
        if ((Num1.length%2)==0) {
            res=DaQMultiplay(Num1, Num2);
            System.out.println(res);
        }
        else{
            String num1 = String.valueOf(Num1);
            num1 = num1+"0";
            String num2 = String.valueOf(Num2);
            num2 = num2+"0";
            Num1=num1.toCharArray();
            Num2=num2.toCharArray();
            res=DaQMultiplay(Num1, Num2);
            res=(res/100);
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally your code isn't handling the case where num2 is resolved to a single digit before num1. This results in an empty string through the DaQ method that ends up throwing your exception. You need to add checking for the handling of num2 resolving first.  This check solves the first exception (around line 46):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rn2.length; i++) {
    if(num2.length>i+lenl){
        rn2[i]=num2[i+lenl];
    }
  }
```

And then you need to add a check in the multiplication phase:
    int num1sd = 1;
int num2sd = 1;

```
if(num1!=null && !num1.equals("") && new String(num2).trim().length()>0){
    num1sd =Integer.parseInt(new String(num1));
}

if(num2!=null && !num2.equals("") && new String(num2).trim().length()>0){
    num2sd=Integer.parseInt(new String(num2));
}
```

i'm not certain if the second check is appropriate to your algorithm as it is written but the general idea is that this if statement `if(num1.length<2){...`only hanldes the case where num1 resolves first and that isn't always the case.

corrected code,but still it passes wrong answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class main {
static int res=0;
static int pow;
static int stage =0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] Num1;
    char[] Num2;
    String num1 = in.nextLine();
    String num2 = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
    Num1 = num1.toCharArray();
    Num2 = num2.toCharArray();
    pow = Num1.length;



    DaQMultiplay(Num1, Num2);
    System.out.println(res);
}
static int DaQMultiplay(char[] num1,char[] num2){
    if(num1.length<2){
        stage++;
        int num1sd = 0;
        int num2sd = 0;
        if(num1!=null && !num1.equals("") && new String(num2).trim().length()>0){
            num1sd =Integer.parseInt(new String(num1));
        }

        if(num2!=null && !num2.equals("") && new String(num2).trim().length()>0){
            num2sd=Integer.parseInt(new String(num2));
        }
        return (num1sd*num2sd);
    }
    stage++;
    double len = num1.length;
    int lenl = (int) Math.ceil(len/2);
    char []ln1 = new char[lenl];
    char []rn1 = new char[(int) (len-lenl)];
    char []ln2 = new char[lenl];
    char []rn2 = new char[(int) (len-lenl)];
    for (int i = 0; i < ln1.length; i++) {
        ln1[i]=num1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rn1.length; i++) {
        rn1[i]=num1[i+lenl];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ln2.length; i++) {
        ln2[i]=num2[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rn2.length; i++) {
        if(num2.length>i+lenl){
            rn2[i]=num2[i+lenl];
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Left Side of num1:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(ln1);

    System.out.print("Right Side of num1:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(rn1);

    System.out.print("Left Side of num2:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(ln2);

    System.out.print("Right Side of num2:"+stage+" ");
    System.out.println(rn2);

    res+=(DaQMultiplay(ln1,ln2)*(Math.pow(10, len)));
    System.out.println(res);
    res+=(DaQMultiplay(rn1,ln2)*(Math.pow(10, (len/2))));
    System.out.println(res);
    res+=(DaQMultiplay(ln1,rn2)*(Math.pow(10, (len/2))));
    System.out.println(res);
    res+=(DaQMultiplay(rn1, rn2));
    System.out.println(res);
    return 0;
}
}
```

new output: num1=,num2=

```
20011
91281
Left Side of num1:1 200
Right Side of num1:1 11
Left Side of num2:1 912
Right Side of num2:1 81
Left Side of num1:2 20
Right Side of num1:2 0
Left Side of num2:2 91
Right Side of num2:2 2
Left Side of num1:3 2
Right Side of num1:3 0
Left Side of num2:3 9
Right Side of num2:3 1
1800
1800
1820
1820
0
0
Left Side of num1:9 2
Right Side of num1:9 0
Left Side of num2:9 2
Right Side of num2:9
```

and the the implementation problem of the algorithm still exist...

Comment: thanks,it solves the error,but still have problem with the correctness of algorithm in conquer steps,i don't know how to handle 4 incoming tail of recursion,my algo based on this doc:
http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~rezaul/Fall-2012/CSE548/CSE548-lecture-2.pdf